# map multi-index of fixed size to integer interval

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to find a bijection between the set of multi-indices $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ of dimensions $d$ with size $|\boldsymbol{\alpha}|\leq r$ and the range of integer of according size. $$\boldsymbol{\alpha}\leftrightarrow k, \qquad k\in\left[1,2,\dots,\begin{pmatrix} d+r \\ r \end{pmatrix}\right].$$

So for example: In the case $d=2$ and $r=2$ I am looking for a mapping $(0,0)\rightarrow 1, (0,1)\rightarrow 2, (0,2)\rightarrow 3, (1,0)\rightarrow 4, (1,1)\rightarrow 5, (2,0)\rightarrow 6$.

What is a nice way to do this?

EDIT: the size of an multi-index $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_d)$ is defined by $| \boldsymbol{\alpha}| = \alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_d$.

Comment: Think of the entries as the digits in a base $b$ representation, choosing $b$ just large enough.

Comment: Hi @EthanBolker I am not sure I understand correctly. Considering my example from the question, am I understanding your hint correctly that you are suggesting to consider everything in basis $r=2$? so for (1,0) I get 10 which would be 4 and 11 would be 5 however 12 would be 6, which I don't have as (1,2) is not in the set.

Comment: If you need an interval and not just an integer encoding then yes this won't do.

Comment: Suggestion: what you are trying to enumerate are all nonincreasing sequences with upper bound n, where the sequence elements are the differences of your coordinates. There's an analogy to discrete simplex coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found a possible way to do it, but it is not pretty and I don't like using it. For dimension $D$ and order $R$

$$f(\alpha) = \sum_{d=1}^D \sum_{p=0}^{\alpha_d-1} \begin{pmatrix} D-d+R-p-\sum_{k=1}^{d-1}\alpha_k \\ R-p-\sum_{k=1}^{d-1}\alpha_k\end{pmatrix} $$

does the trick apparently. but it is really useless and hard to compute so I would really like to see a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very nice reference, Computational aspects of multivariate polynomial interpolation: Indexing the coefficients Carl de Boor, detailing the case where polynomial are given in graded lexicographic order. Also applying it to resolve the Horner/de Boor scheme to revaluate polynomials, similar to what I am doing.